# How to add/subtract a day

Tags: sql, web-sql, opendatabase

How can I subtract (or add) days from a `dateandtime` or `smalldatetime` date in `Web SQL`? I have tried searching for it, but couldn't find anything.

The solutions that exist are all for `SQL` and `MySQL`.

I have tried: `DATEADD` (SQL), and `DATE_ADD/DATE_SUB` (MySQL) functions.

Both are giving errors (even when I copy paste simple example statements), when I use them on my web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (change now for te time string, or leave now to add or substract from today)

`SELECT date('now','+1 day');` or `SELECT date('now','-1 day');`

EDIT:

If you want to add or substract to an specific day, you would need to format the date as following

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

then you could use `date` or `datetime` and add/substract the day. Using the data from the comment:

```
SELECT DATE('2017-08-24 09:05:00','-1 days') --returns 2017-08-23
SELECT DATETIME('2017-08-24 09:05:00','+1 days'); --returns 2017-08-25 09:05:00
```

Comment: It works when I use 'now'. How can I make it work for a smalldatetime object/variable? Suppose I have a variable called max1, which is in the smalldatetime format: '2017-8-24 9:5:00' - how can I add/ subtract from this?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works when I use a datetime value, but not when I have a smalldatetime value.So I have something like: '2017-8-26 7:15:00' instead of '2017-08-24 07:15:00'. And it returns a null.

Comment: Is there any function I can use on smalldatetime like in the above? [I don't want to use convert/cast because this is part of a nested query like: "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN ( nested query for max value - x days ) AND ( max value )"; and I need the output to be in smalldatetime as well ].

Comment: You might need to convert them, http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html you can find the time strings formats.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. (Actually I was making a mistake. It was giving error not because it was in 'smalldatetime' format, but because the format I inserted them was incorrect. Strangely this wrong format worked when I used simple queries of searching between dates, but gave error when I tried to perform date functions [adding/subtracting dates] like the above. Now when I have corrected the entries in the db, your code above works perfectly).

Comment: Glad it helped :)